# what is the difference betwen timestamp in java and php?

Tags: java, php, datetime, timestamp

I have a **java** file that write records to the DB and time stamps

I have another **php** file that reads that records..

unfortunately After converting the time stamp to dates I got a wrong dates ??

what is the problem !!!

Comment: What lib are you using in java? in php?
what db?
did you checked http://joda-time.sourceforge.net?

Comment: Can you please show your code for both recording the timestamp with and retrieving it with PHP? This will help you get an answer more quickly.

Answer (score 10):

Java uses a timestamp which is milliseconds from the epoch.  PHP uses the standard unix timestamp which is seconds from the epoch.

I believe both use the same epoch of Jan. 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC

Answer (score 2):

PHP uses the UNIX epoch, I suspect Java uses a different epoch.

EDIT: I was way off, turns out PHP uses seconds, java uses miliseconds. So multiply by 1000 or divide by 1000 depending on which way you're converting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're retrieving a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column or such that has been stored and screwing up the conversion. Try this:

```
$phpdate = strtotime( $dateFromDb );
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $phpdate);
```